Distributions Theory - Lipschitz function defined by a L-infinity function
Let $g \in L^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and define $f(x) := \int_{a}^{x} g(y)dy, x \in \mathbb{R}.$ Prove that $f$ is well-defined and it's a Lipschitz function with $f'=g$ em $\mathcal{D}' (\mathbb{R}).$
I tried to use Fundamental Calculus Theorem and the definition of derivate of a distribution but I didn't get what I wanted.

I assume $a$ is an element in $\mathbb R$?

First and foremost, I assume $a\in \mathbb R$ (otherwise how would one make sense of the integral?). Next we will show that $f$ is well defined. Since $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ it is bounded almost every where. So the integral over a compact set $[a,b]$ where $a,b\in\mathbb R$ is finite. We see that for every $x\in \mathbb R$ the set $[a,x]$ is compact and thus $f(x)=\int_a^xg(y)dy$ is finite. That is $f$ is well-defined.
Next we want to show that the derivative of $f$ is $g$ in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$. Let $\phi$ be a test function, then by definition of distributional derivative we have
$$\langle f',\phi\rangle = -\langle f,\phi'\rangle = -\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\phi'(x)dx = \int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_a^xg(y)dy\right)\phi'(x)dx = *.$$
Using partial integration we obtain the following:
$$* = \int f'(x)\phi(x)dx = \int_\mathbb R\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_a^xg(y)dy\right]\phi(x)dx = \int_\mathbb R g(x)\phi(x)dx = \langle g,\phi\rangle.$$
This shows that $f'=g$ in the sense of distributions. Note that the first term we obtain from partial integration vanishes due to $\phi$ having compact support.
I forgot to show that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. Let $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb R$, without loss of generality assume that $x_1\leq x_2$. Then
$$\vert f(x_1)-f(x_2)\vert = \left\vert \int_a^{x_1}  g(y)dy - \int_a^{x_2}g(y)dy \right\vert \leq \int_{x_2}^{x_1}\vert g(y)\vert dy \leq \|g\|_\infty \vert x_1-x_2\vert.$$
The desired Lipschitz constant is $\|g\|_\infty$.

It's possible to solve with $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

@UchihaItachi how do you define the integral $\int_a^xg(y)dy$ if $a\in \mathbb C$?

I don't know how to make sense of that...
